# else if in Python 2.7

Tags: python

The purpose of this code isn't important,but I'm getting an indentation error.  They are usually really obvious fixes, but in this case I don't see why the error comes up.

```
group=0
for i in range(0,len(line)):
   for j in range(0,len(both)):
        if both[j]==line[i]:
        elif both[j]==line[i]-1:
                group+=1
```

Comment: There's nothing inside your if-block

Comment: You could improve the readability of your code by following the "PEP8 Style Guide" on [Whitespaces in Expressions and Statements](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements), especially "Other Recommendations".

Answer (score 3):

There isn't anything in your if block, if you want nothing to happen, use a `pass`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is an empty block - you must have something after the `if` conditional, you can use a do-nothing keyword `pass`.

Since you are not using `i` or `j` here for anything other than indexing the container, it is also more pythonic and readable to iterate the container directly which would look like this:

```
group = 0
for i in line:
  for j in both:
    if j == i:
      pass
    elif j == i - 1:
      group += 1
```